# Having some problem getting the uvs working right with vulkan raytracing

Tags: c++, 3d, game-engine, vulkan, raytracing

I've been working with ray-tracing for about a month so I'm still getting used it. I'm having some problems getting the uvs to look right.  Here's the shader I'm working with, I think the problem has something to do with v.uv = vec2(d0.x,  d1.y); in the unpack function. I've been playing around with it for a while but haven't been having any luck. I've also tried making a uv buffer and directly sending the info directly into and working from that, but it only works with one mesh then looks messed up after that.

[image]

```
#version 460
#extension GL_EXT_ray_tracing : require
#extension GL_EXT_nonuniform_qualifier : enable

layout(location = 0) rayPayloadInEXT vec3 hitValue;
layout(location = 2) rayPayloadEXT bool shadowed;
hitAttributeEXT vec2 attribs;

struct VertexData
{
    vec3 Position;
    vec3 Normal;
    vec2 UV;
    vec3 Tangent;
    vec3 BiTangent;
};


struct DirectionalLight
{
    vec3 direction;
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

struct PointLight 
{
    vec3 position;
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
    float constant;
    float linear;
    float quadratic;
};

struct MaterialInfo
{
    vec3 Ambient;
    vec3 Diffuse;
    vec3 Specular;    
    float Shininess;
    float Reflectivness;

    uint DiffuseMapID;
    uint SpecularMapID;
    uint NormalMapID;
    uint DepthMapID;
    uint AlphaMapID;
    uint EmissionMapID;
};

struct Material
{
    vec3 Ambient;
    vec3 Diffuse;
    vec3 Specular;    
    float Shininess;
    float Reflectivness;

    vec3 DiffuseMap;
    vec3 SpecularMap;
    vec3 NormalMap;
    vec3 DepthMap;
    vec3 AlphaMap;
    vec3 EmissionMap;
};

layout(binding = 0) uniform accelerationStructureEXT topLevelAS;
layout(binding = 2) uniform UBO 
{
    mat4 viewInverse;
    mat4 projInverse;
    mat4 modelInverse;
    DirectionalLight dlight;
    vec3 viewPos;
    PointLight plight;
    int vertexSize;
} ubo;
layout(binding = 3) buffer Vertices { vec4 v[]; } vertices[];
layout(binding = 4) buffer Indices { uint i[]; } indices[];
layout(binding = 5) buffer MaterialInfos { MaterialInfo materialInfo[]; } MaterialList;
layout(binding = 6) uniform sampler2D TextureMap[];

struct Vertex
{
  vec3 pos;
  vec3 normal;
  vec2 uv;
  vec4 tangent;
  vec4 BiTangant;
  vec4 Color;
  vec4 BoneID;
  vec4 BoneWeights;
 };


Vertex unpack(uint index)
{
    const int m = ubo.vertexSize / 16;

    vec4 d0 = vertices[gl_InstanceCustomIndexEXT].v[m * index + 0];
    vec4 d1 = vertices[gl_InstanceCustomIndexEXT].v[m * index + 1];
    vec4 d2 = vertices[gl_InstanceCustomIndexEXT].v[m * index + 2];

    Vertex v;
    v.pos = d0.xyz;
    v.normal = vec3(d0.w, d1.x, d1.y);
    v.Color = vec4(d2.x, d2.y, d2.z, 1.0);
    v.uv = vec2(d0.x, 
                d1.y);
    v.tangent = vec4(d0.w, d1.y, d1.y, 0.0f);

    return v;
}

Material BuildMaterial(vec2 UV)
{
    Material material;
    material.Ambient = MaterialList.materialInfo[gl_InstanceCustomIndexEXT].Ambient;
    material.Diffuse = MaterialList.materialInfo[gl_InstanceCustomIndexEXT].Diffuse;
    material.Specular = MaterialList.materialInfo[gl_InstanceCustomIndexEXT].Specular;
    material.Shininess = MaterialList.materialInfo[gl_InstanceCustomIndexEXT].Shininess;
    material.Reflectivness = MaterialList.materialInfo[gl_InstanceCustomIndexEXT].Reflectivness;
    material.DiffuseMap = vec3(texture(TextureMap[MaterialList.materialInfo[gl_InstanceCustomIndexEXT].DiffuseMapID], UV));
    material.SpecularMap = vec3(texture(TextureMap[MaterialList.materialInfo[gl_InstanceCustomIndexEXT].SpecularMapID], UV));
    material.NormalMap = vec3(texture(TextureMap[MaterialList.materialInfo[gl_InstanceCustomIndexEXT].NormalMapID], UV));
    material.AlphaMap = vec3(texture(TextureMap[MaterialList.materialInfo[gl_InstanceCustomIndexEXT].AlphaMapID], UV));
    material.EmissionMap = vec3(texture(TextureMap[MaterialList.materialInfo[gl_InstanceCustomIndexEXT].EmissionMapID], UV));
    return material;
};

void main()
{
    const ivec3 index = ivec3(indices[gl_InstanceCustomIndexEXT].i[3 * gl_PrimitiveID], 
                              indices[gl_InstanceCustomIndexEXT].i[3 * gl_PrimitiveID + 1], 
                              indices[gl_InstanceCustomIndexEXT].i[3 * gl_PrimitiveID + 2]);

    const Vertex v0 = unpack(index.x);
    const Vertex v1 = unpack(index.y);
    const Vertex v2 = unpack(index.z);

    const vec2 uv0 = getTexCoord(index.x);
    const vec2 uv1 = getTexCoord(index.y);
    const vec2 uv2 = getTexCoord(index.z);

    // Interpolate normal
    const vec3 barycentricCoords = vec3(1.0f - attribs.x - attribs.y, attribs.x, attribs.y);
    vec3 normal = normalize(v0.normal * barycentricCoords.x + v1.normal * barycentricCoords.y + v2.normal * barycentricCoords.z);
    vec2 UV = v0.uv * barycentricCoords.x + v1.uv * barycentricCoords.y + v2.uv * barycentricCoords.z;
     vec3 worldPos = v0.pos * barycentricCoords.x + v1.pos * barycentricCoords.y + v2.pos * barycentricCoords.z;

        const Material material = BuildMaterial(UV);

    vec3 lightDir = normalize(-ubo.dlight.direction);
    float diff = max(dot(ubo.dlight.direction, lightDir), 0.0);

    vec3 ambient = ubo.dlight.ambient *  material.DiffuseMap;
    vec3 diffuse = ubo.dlight.diffuse * diff *  material.DiffuseMap;
 
     hitValue = ambient + diffuse;


        vec3 lightDir2 = normalize(ubo.plight.position - worldPos);
    float diff2 = max(dot(ubo.plight.position, lightDir2), 0.0);
     float distance = length(ubo.plight.position - worldPos);
    float attenuation = 1.0 / (ubo.plight.constant + ubo.plight.linear * distance + ubo.plight.quadratic * (distance * distance));    
    
    vec3 ambient2 = ubo.plight.ambient * material.DiffuseMap;
    vec3 diffuse2 = ubo.plight.diffuse * diff * material.DiffuseMap;
//  ambient2 *= attenuation;
  //  diffuse2 *= attenuation;

     hitValue += ambient2 + diffuse2;















    float spec = 0.0f;
//  if(dot(normal, L) > 0)
//  {
    // Shadow casting
    float tmin = 0.001;
    float tmax = 10000.0;
    vec3 origin = gl_WorldRayOriginEXT + gl_WorldRayDirectionEXT * gl_HitTEXT;
    shadowed = true;  
    // Trace shadow ray and offset indices to match shadow hit/miss shader group indices
    traceRayEXT(topLevelAS, gl_RayFlagsTerminateOnFirstHitEXT | gl_RayFlagsOpaqueEXT | gl_RayFlagsSkipClosestHitShaderEXT, 0xFF, 1, 0, 1, origin, tmin, lightDir, tmax, 2);
    if (shadowed) {
        hitValue *= 0.3f;
    }
    else
    {
        vec3 halfwayDir = normalize(ubo.dlight.direction + ubo.viewPos);  
         spec = pow(max(dot(normal, halfwayDir), 0.0), material.Shininess);
        vec3 specular = ubo.dlight.specular * spec * material.Specular;
        hitValue += specular;
    }

    traceRayEXT(topLevelAS, gl_RayFlagsTerminateOnFirstHitEXT | gl_RayFlagsOpaqueEXT | gl_RayFlagsSkipClosestHitShaderEXT, 0xFF, 1, 0, 1, origin, tmin, lightDir2, tmax, 2);
    if (shadowed) {
        hitValue *= 0.3f;
    }
    else
    {
        vec3 halfwayDir2 = normalize(ubo.plight.position + ubo.viewPos);  
        spec = pow(max(dot(normal, halfwayDir2), 0.0), material.Shininess);
        vec3 specular2 = ubo.plight.specular * spec * material.Specular;
        //specular2 *= attenuation;
        hitValue += specular2;
    }
        
 //  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`v.uv = vec2(d0.x, d1.y);` surely looks wrong, as `d0.x` contains the vertex position's `x` component, and not the `u` component of your texture coordinates. Same for the `v` component that is wrongly taken from the normal's `w` component. As you didn't post the layout of your vertex on the host side, I can only guess, but if your host vertex layout is something like this :

```
glm::vec3 pos;
glm::vec3 normal;
glm::vec2 uv;
```

And you unpack into multiple vec4s, you get this:

```
vec4 0: pos.x|pos.y|pos.z|normal.x 
vec4 1: normal.y|normal.z|uv.u|uv.v
```

This means that you need to fetch your data like this:

```
v.pos = d0.xyz;
v.normal = vec3(d0.w, d1.x, d1.y);
v.uv = d1.zw;
```